# Returning a value pointed to by a pointer in x86 NASM

Tags: pointers, x86, nasm

I'm trying to write a function in x86 NASM assembly that takes a pointer to a structure (structure contains pointer to a buffer) and 2 ints (x,y) which then computes the address of the byte containing (x,y) and returns the value in this address. (The buffer contains a bmp file) I have this function written in C and it works fine.

**C function**

```
int loadByte(imgInfo* pImg, int x, int y)
{
    unsigned char *pPix = pImg->pImg + (((pImg->width + 31) >> 5) << 2) * y + (x >> 3);
    return *pPix;
}
```

**x86 function**

```
load_byte:
    push ebp           ; prologue
    mov ebp, esp  

    lea ecx, [ebp + 8]  
    mov ecx, [ecx]      ; ecx = &imgInfo
    mov eax, [ecx+0]    ; eax = width
    add eax, 31         ; eax = width + 31
    sar eax, 5          ; eax = (width + 31) >> 5
    sal eax, 2          ; eax = ((width + 31) >> 5) << 2
    mul DWORD [ebp+16]  ; eax * y
    mov edx, [ebp+12]   ; edx = x
    sar edx, 3          ; edx = x>>3
    add eax, edx        ; eax = ((width + 31) >> 5) << 2 * y + (x >> 3)
    mov edx, [ecx+8]    ; edx = &pImg
    add eax, edx
    mov eax, [eax]

    pop ebp            ; epilogue
    ret
```

I tried checking if the address computed in both functions is the same so I changed the return of C to `return pPix` and commented the line `mov eax, [eax]` in x86 and to my surprise both functions returned the same number but in the unchanged form (as in the code above) the x86 function always returns -1 for some reason. Is `return *pPix` not equivalent to `mov eax, [eax]`? What is wrong with my reasoning?

**imgInfo struct**

```
typedef struct
{
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* pImg;    //buffer
    int cX, cY;
    int col;
} imgInfo;
```

**load_byte C declaration**

`extern int load_byte(imgInfo* pInfo, int x, int y);`

Comment: `return *pPix` should be `movzx eax, byte [eax]`

Comment: If you're not going to use the high half result of `mul` (in EDX), just use a more efficient `imul eax, [ebp+16]` that only writes the destination register.